# Jest/Enzyme: The snapshot files size increased (2.7 millions LOC) once I migrated from CRA to Webpack5

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

I was previously using Create React App for my project. Jest was integrated previously and for one of my component it made a snapshot of 0.25 million. Now I am migrating to a new repository with the same code but with Webpack 5 configuration. But now the snapshots are coming around 2.7 million LOC which is not allowing me to push the code to my github enterprise. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to avoid it?